# Problemas para recuperar una variable estática de una clase

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, diseño-de-clases

Estoy aprendiendo Clases. He creado la clase que muestro a continuación, conformada por 7 métodos, que me permiten, realizando las correspondientes instanciaciones, obtener 7 listas a partir de un DataFrame al que he ido añadiendo columnas.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

class VariacionCotizaciones:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df       

    def calc_variacion_diaria(self):
        # Variación diaria de las cotizaciones
        for i in range (0, self.df.shape[0]):
            self.df["Var_dia"] = self.df[nom_val] - self.df[nom_val].shift(-1)       
        return self.df
    
    def calcula_variacion_diaria_acumulada(self):
       # Variaciones diarias acumuladas
        self.df["Var_dia_acum"] = self.df["Var_dia"].cumsum() 
        return self.df["Var_dia_acum"]
    
    def calc_medias_mensuales(self):
        # media de las cotizaciones mensuales.
        media_mens = self.df.resample('M').mean()
        media_mens["Mes"] = media_mens.index.month
        return media_mens
        
    def calc_medias_4_meses(self):        
        # Media de las cotizaciones de períodos de  4 meses.
        media_4meses = self.df.resample("4M").mean()       
        return media_4meses
    
    def calc_media_anual(self):
        # Media de las cotizaciones anuales
        media_anual = self.df.resample("Y").mean().reset_index()
        return media_anual
    
    def calc_porcentaje_diario_cambios(self):
        # Porcentaje de variación diaria
        self.df["Pct_var_dia"] = self.df[nom_val].pct_change()
        return  self.df["Pct_var_dia"]
        
    def calcula_pct_retornos_diarios_acumulados(self):
        # Cálculo de los retornos diarios acumulados
        self.df["Pct_var_dia_acum"] = (1 + self.df["Pct_var_dia"]).cumprod()
        return self.df["Pct_var_dia_acum"]     
    

df = pdr.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', "2018", "2021")    
datos = df[["Close"]]  

cotizaciones =  VariacionCotizaciones(datos)      

var_dia = cotizaciones.calc_variacion_diaria()
var_dia_acums = cotizaciones.calcula_variacion_diaria_acumulada()
media_var_mens = cotizaciones.calc_medias_mensuales()
media_var_4meses = cotizaciones.calc_medias_4_meses()
media_var_anuales = cotizaciones.calc_media_anual()
pct_diario_cambio = cotizaciones.calc_porcentaje_diario_cambios()
pct_diario_cambio_acumulados = cotizaciones.calcula_pct_retornos_diarios_acumulados()

VariacionCotizaciones.df
```

Cuando intento obtener el DataFrame modificado con las columnas añadidas, llamando a la variable estática **df** de la clase, me devuelve el error
VariacionCotizaciones.df

```
AttributeError: type object 'VariacionCotizaciones' has no attribute 'df'
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener este DataFrame **df** modificado?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Teoría

El atributo `df` de tu implementación no es una variable estática de clase. Todo lo contrario, es un atributo propio de una instancia y no de la clase.

La diferencia entre un atributo de clase y uno de instancia es que al atributo de clase puedes acceder usando `NombreDeLaClase.atributo`, y que es compartido por todas las instancias de esa misma clase. Un atributo de instancia en cambio pertenece a cada objeto particular instanciado a partir de una clase, y para acceder a él debes usar `nombre_de_objeto.atributo` si estás "fuera" del objeto, o bien mediante `self.atributo` si estás dentro un método del objeto.

La palabra  `self` no es palabra reservada ni tiene ningún significado especial para el intérprete. Es sólo un convenio que se sigue a la hora de poner un nombre al primer parámetro que reciben todos los métodos, y que el intérprete rellena automáticamente con el objeto en cuestión sobre el que se esté operando.

Es decir, cuando tú instancias un objeto con, por ejemplo:

```
cotizaciones =  VariacionCotizaciones(datos)
```

Python creará una nueva instancia a partir de la clase, asignará a la variable `cotizaciones` una referencia a esa nueva instancia, e invocará `cotizaciones.__init__(datos)`.

A su vez, cada vez que invoques cualquier método (incluído `__init__()`) sobre esa instancia, por ejemplo usando `cotizaciones.calc_variacion_diaria()`, Python convierte esa llamada en una llamada al método de la clase, que recibe como primer parámetro el objeto en cuestión. Es decir, se convertiría en `VariacionCotizaciones.calc_variacion_diaria(cotizaciones)`.

Así es como el objeto `cotizaciones` llega como primer parámetro al método. Y ya que en ese método has llamado `self` al primer parámetro, `self` representa en ese momento al objeto `cotizaciones`. Por tanto cuando accedas a `self.df` estás accediendo a `cotizaciones.df`, un atributo específico de ese objeto (y que no está en la clase).

De ese modo, si crearas varias instancias de la clase, cada instancia tendría su propio atributo `.df`.

Esto es lo habitualmente usado. La posibilidad de tener atributos de clase se usa mucho más raramente para poder compartir una cierta información entre todas las instancias.

### Solucion

Por tanto basta que accedas a `cotizaciones.df` para obtener lo que querías.

Comment: Efectivamente,  df no es una variable estática sino una variable particular para cada instancia de la clase.
En la sentencia "cotizaciones = VariacionCotizaciones(datos)" es donde se crea la instancia de la clase que se almacena en la variable "cotizaciones". Así que con  poner "cotizaciones.df", nos devuelve el df modificado. Gracias.